# Como posso exibir somente os nomes dos pacotes enquanto estão sendo descompactado

Tags: linux, script, bash, shell

A pergunta que talvez já têm alguma resposta, no entanto não encontrei.

Estou meio que perdido, diria que um pouco que confuso até porque o que estou a perguntar acho que já o fiz em alguma circunstância da vida mas não estou conseguindo me recorda ao certo como. Era algo mais-ou-menos assim:

## Código

```
#Auto-installar pacotes TARBALL no sistema Linux
for N in "/tmp/{abiword, gnumeric, inkscape, gimp, firefox}.tgz" 
do 
    echo -e "$N\t" && sudo tar zxf $N -C /; 
done
```

**Rápida Explicação**

Este comando `echo` seguido de seu parâmetro `-e` indica que deve-se exibir o nome(palavra) uma após a outra estando na mesma linha. Tendo como um breve espaçamento entre cada nome de pacotes. Este espaço é definido pelo operador `\t`

Para o comando `tar` me reservei de não por o argumento `-z`, para não vazar o fluxo no momento de extração.

Bom, enfim! O que quero, é mostrar apenas cada nome(s) de pacote(s) a cada instante que, o comando `tar` termina de extrair um pacote e, passar para o próximo e assim sucessivamente até findar o ciclo.

Então fica deste modo, o `loop` percorrer o diretório `/tmp` onde estão situados os pacotes `*.tgz`, e deve setar o nome do primeiro pacote na tela e em continuidade o trabalho pesado fica por conta do `tar` que por sua vez descompacteia para o sistema o primeiro pacote, e o `loop` torna a percorrer o diretório `/tmp` e novamente seta o segundo nome do segundo pacote e passa o controle para o `tar` realizar sua tarefa, e assim por diante ... até que se esgote o ciclo posto no `loop`.

Sendo ao todo instalado(s) no momento dando assim, uma estimativa para que o usuário tenha paciência pois o sistema se encarregou de auto-instalar o TARBALL alojado na pasta.

Comment: se eu entendi certo, você tem q utilizar o comando `tar -xf $N` assim ele estrai o conteúdo sem mostrar quais arquivos estão sendo extraídos.

Comment: @BrumazziDB Oops! errei feio, `z` que da o print do fluxo quando esta extraindo, me confunde  com o `v`. Mas de todo modo [BrumazziDB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/39338/brumazzi-db). Note que eu preciso é destacar o nome sem a extenssão do pacote, ocultar o fluxo dos dados enquanto o `tar` faz seu trabalho, e terminando a primeira extração, vai para o segundo pacote exibe seu nome logo a frente do primeiro pacote, passa o controle para o `tar` executar e terminado a segunda extração, agora mostra o terceiro nome do pacote a frente do segundo e começa a extração, e vai para o quarto etc.

Comment: Acho q entendi se o pacote se chama `firefox.tar` vc quer que escreve `firefox`, correto?

Comment: @BrumazziDB Sim! Esta correto sua suposição. Note que, ele deve primeiro exibir o nome do pacote em questão no qual será descompactado, dando um certo tempo de um para outro, afim de mostrar o nome do seguinte pacote a ser descompactado, e então prosseguir para o próximo. Isso que pretendo é semelhante a um **Progress-bar**, visualizando o nome do arquivo pelo qual se esta extraindo os dados naquele momento, e por assim se fazer com todos, conforme vai sendo extraido, também vai sendo exibido o nome do pacote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em *ShellScript* existem instruções nativas para fazer a manipulação da *String*, remove uma sequencia de caracteres do final da *String* é uma delas, e para isso usa-se a instrução `%`.

Seu uso deve estar dentro de chave logo após o testo que deseja recortar a sequencia.

```
$ TEXTO="test.sh"
$ echo "${TEXTO%.sh}"
> test
```

Em seu código basta colocar apos `N`:

```
for N in "/tmp/{abiword, gnumeric, inkscape, gimp, firefox}.tgz" 
do 
    echo -e "${N%.tgz}\t" && sudo tar zxf $N -C /; 
done
```

Agora para separar a extração, pode-se criar um instrução para auxiliar a marcação do tempo.

```
#!/bin/bash

BREAK=/tmp/i.lock

function count(){ # função para contar o tempo
    touch /tmp/i.lock
    while [ -f "$BREAK" ]; do
        sleep 0.5
        echo -n "."
    done
}

for N in "/tmp/{abiword, gnumeric, inkscape, gimp, firefox}.tgz"; do
    echo -n "Instalando ${N%.tgz}"
    count & # inicia o contador
    tar zxf $N -C /
    rm -f /tmp/i.lock # encerra o contador
    echo " ok"
    let TEMP=0
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Posto aqui também o que tenho feito, servindo apenas para futura consulta.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Local onde suponho que estejam os pacotes TARBALL
I='/tmp' 

# Listamos com todos formato *.tgz com o comando "ls" 
# Logo recortarmos o nomes com "cut -d '/'" após a barra slash "/" 
# Na qual pegamos apenas a coluna 2 com o parâmetro "-f2"
O=`ls -1 $I/*.tgz | cut -d '/' -f2`

# Agora aplicamos o laço "for" para percorrer cada uma das instrução
# Definimos a variável para execução condizente com a pasta e arquivos
for N in $O
do 

# Adentramos pra dentro da pasta "/tmp" no qual vamos descompactar o(s) pacote(s)
    cd $I

# Os demais comandos abaixo fazem seu trabalho de uma barra de progresso
    sleep 0.25
    echo -ne "\r" 
    sleep 0.25 
    echo -ne "\r>" 
    sleep 0.25  
    echo -ne "\r>>"
    sleep 0.25 
    echo -ne "\r>>>"
    sleep 0.25 

# Aliado a Barra de Progresso, temos ${N%.tgz} que nos ilustra o nome do(s) pacote(s) sem o formato final(tgz), por conta do "%" que oculta.
    echo -ne "\r>>>> ${N%.tgz}"

# Realizando a extração pra dentro do filesystem(sistema de arquivos)
    sudo tar zxf "$N" -C /
    echo " ok" 

# Daqui em diante damos um intervalo mínimo para retomada do laço
    sleep 1
done
```

Bem, o ponto fundamental da pergunta assim como na(s) resposta(s) foi o símbolo `%`, que se aplicado antes de qualquer extensão e/ou palavra posto entre as chaves `${..}`, isto anula o que vem depois do símbolo `%`, sendo visualizado apenas o que nos interessa.

Answer (score 0):

No **tar** você pode usar a opção **-v** que é de verbose.